# My ban command for some reason doesn't work, and I don't know hot to fix it (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a ban command about a month ago for my bot, and a few days ago, it just stopped working. Does anyone know why?
Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'ban'
```

I need all the help I can get. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add more code? The error doesn't make sense at all

Comment: Print the type of each argument. You probably have parameter mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing the command in the a Cog. all methods (functions) in a class (in this case, Cog) have their first set as `self` which is the class itself.

Because you didn't passed "self" "ctx" is being used as it, basically your command is missing one parameter. Try this:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

Also, take into consideration that `commands.has_permissions` works only on the current channel, you probably want to use `commands.has_guild_permissions` instead

Comment: when using cogs the decorator is not “client.command”, it’s “commands.command”

Comment: Yeah thats true, ill edit that (just copied and pasted), but he's probably making the same mistake. There's no othere reason i can think of for the error he's getting

Comment: I don't use cogs